# How to json serialize and send a big data efficiently in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, serialization

I am currently serializing and sending files to my web api with a minimum size of 5mb, and i achieved this using [JSONMODEL](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel). Even though i am already using an **iPhone 6 Plus** as a test device, serializing the data i gathered takes up 99% of cpu usage, plus sending the data is taking way too long, is there any other way on how to make serializing less of a hassle for the phone? and also sending the data, when implementing **chunking** *(i only saw that in some forums ^^)* do i still need to configure the webapi? and would gzip/deflate help? thanks guys! :D

Answer (score 0):

I always use "JSONKit" Framework to parse JSON data，You used this yet?